# How to generate ListView with Jackson and RoboSpice

Tags: android, json, listview, jackson, robospice

So i have all of my RoboSpice methods and classes ready, set up and working, now i am trying to use jackson to generate a listview. I think my problem is in my controller.

Here is the error i get.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at myapp.myapp.PostController.init(PostController.java:31)
        at myapp.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

==================================================================================
Here is my controller. Keep in mind the Json array does not have a name.

```
public class PostController {
private final String json = "my url is in there";

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;
private JsonFactory jsonFactory = null;
private JsonParser jp = null;
private ArrayList<Post> posts = null;
private Posts mPosts = null;

public PostController() {
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
}

public void init() {
    try {
        jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < mPosts.size(); i++) {
            posts = mPosts.get(i);
        }

    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Post> findAll() {
    return posts;
}

public Post findById(int id) {
    return posts.get(id);
}
```

Here is my onCreate

```
ListView mListView;
protected SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(JsonSpiceService.class);
TextView postName, description;
PostController postController = new PostController();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().show();
    getActionBar().setTitle("");

    performRequest();
    postController.init();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mListView);
    MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item, postController.findAll());
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this is how i am trying to generate the items for the listview.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    // declaring our ArrayList of posts
    ArrayList<Post> posts;

    /* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
    * the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Post> objects,
    * because it is the list of objects we want to display.
    */
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Post> posts) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, posts);
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    /*
     * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
     * list item will look.
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_view_item, null);
        postController.init();
        postController.findAll();

        for(Post post: postController.findAll()){
            postName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postName);
            description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

            postName.setText(post.getName());
            description.setText(post.getDesc());
        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to be initializing your posts array in your PostController?  Looks like you'll get a NullPointerException when init is called.

Comment: @MichaelKrause oncreate is suppose to initialize it.